# Why was the Communications Carrier Assembly black and white?

Tags: spacesuits, color

I understand the CCA, the headset for NASA astronauts, was made up of [lycra and teflon fabrics](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19740011700.pdf).  Is there a reason, relevant to space flight, that the two materials were different colors?

[image: Photo of astronaut Donn Eisele adjusting his CCA. The central band of the CCA is white lycra, the side panels are dark teflon fabric.]

Comment: The teflon side panels are actually a dark brown rather than black, FWIW. In some photos they appear quite light; some of that may be them fading with age.

Comment: I've read through everything NASA has on it, and no definitive answer.  Tech note D-8093 describes its history but says nothing about colors.  NAS 9-7976 discusses materials.  If anyone has the physical book Kosloski, Lillian D. *U.S. Space Gear: Outfitting the Astronaut.* Washington, DC: Smithsonian Institution Press, 1993, it may be your best bet.

Comment: Educated guess: The dark colors reduce glare.  D-8093 does talk about this as the reason for the *side visors* outside the pressure helmet, which are painted black on their inward side.  The top portion may have been left its natural white color because of concerns that dyeing it would affect its elasticity.